# Custom django permissions for group chats?

Tags: python, django

I have a custom group model like this:

```py
class MyGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=False,default="Group name")
    members = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), blank=True, related_name="grpmembers")
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=False, related_name="createdby+")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
```

It works, it's fine, I override the save method in django admin so the created_by will point to the logged in user on save.

**Problem #1**

Even if you are the creator of the group, you can select yourself to either be in- or be removed from the group which kinda looks silly. I'm thinking of solving this by saying the user can view the group if they're in `members` or `created_by`.

**Problem #2**

Custom permission. I want to have some permissions, like:

- Can view the group: which means the user is either the creator or is in the members list
- Can edit the group: which means the user is the creator(can edit their own) or is staff(can edit anyone's stuff) or is superuser(root)

I can write it down and imagine how it would work, but I have no idea how to implement these.

I've found some ways, like creating a Meta and defining permissions there and also making the permissions as def(/functions), but how could I access the currently logged in user?

Like okay let's say I do

```py
def can_view_group(self):
r1 = self.filter(members=req.user) # where req.uset is not accessible bc we're in models.py
```

, but how do I tell the permission to check the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is doing all the logic in models.
Over problem 1 you need to verify user is not owner before allow to leave in the views.py.
Over the problem 2 are 2 solutions, or you move can_view_group to views.py, or you define that in models as:

```
def can_view_group(self, user):
    #all the logic
```

And you pass the user from views.py